# Solve $\frac{x}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}-\pi=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Solve $\frac{x}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}-\pi=0$

I'm aware there will be an infinite number of answers. Can you solve this exactly or does it have to be done numerically?

Comment: I don't see a reason for $1.0293780321636440648730078801884412789\ldots$ to be expressibly in a simple way. For $x\gg 0$ we need $x\approx (k+\frac12)\pi$, which may lead to a nice series representation.